# Поддерживает ли GOlang 1.11 arm v7 linux ?

Tags: golang, arm

Поддерживает ли GOlang  1.11 arm v7 linux? Железо: однопалатный микрокомпьютер Orange PI PC  с установленным Armbian 5.60 ( Ubuntu 16.04.5 TLS xenial 3.4.113-sun8i). Из официального репозитория Armbian ставится Golang 1.5.  Обновил вручную до GOlang 1.11  приложения компилятся без ошибок, но работают лишь частично. Например,  не подгружаются html-templates. Хотя до этого на версии 1.5 все работало.

Comment: Можно глянуть в сторону GoArm

Comment: Golang v.1.5 работает, а вот v.1.11 некорректно. Собирал как ARM=6  так и под ARM=7. Не хочет работать с html templates. Но обратная же совместимость должна же быть, раз на 1.5 работало, то и на 1.11 должно?

Comment: Конечно должно, видимо ручное обновление не всовсем корректно работает, другой вопрос почему, я думаю что проблема именно в новой сборке.

Comment: Если программа запускается, но работает неверно, с вероятностью 99% у вас ошибка в коде. Возможно вы использовали какое-то некорректное поведение, которое с тех пор было починено. Без кода сказать невозможно.